# How do I change the "global zone" content/size for Google TV apps?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, google-tv

I've read the [Google TV Design Patterns](http://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_android_patterns.html) article and still can't figure out how to change the default "global" zone size/position or how to get more than one item to show up in it.

There are some vague (to me) statements.  E.g.: "Because the global zone persists throughout the life of the application, you should not allow it to take up too much screen space.".  (OK, how do I change it in the layout?)

It then states that the global zone "[...] holds all of the top-level **'global'** items in your application hierarchy [...]".  Then goes on to state "It also contains all the **categories** for your application [...]"

What is considered a global item?  An activity with a "LAUNCHER" and "MAIN" <intent-filter> category and action?  (Tried that and no joy)

What do "categories" mean?  Categories as defined in each activity's <intent-filter> "category" manifest entry? (Tried that too and no joy)

I've run through the SDK's ApiDemos code relating to Fragments and it's not jumping out at me.  I have successfully ported part of an existing app to extend Fragment and ListFragment but for the life of me can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

The global zone could be implemented by a fragment that is the size you wish it to be.  There are no requirements that you use something else, like an ActionBar.

Comment: But where in the layout is it the global fragment defined?

I experimented with both [Diane Hackborn's example from the Android Developers Blog](http://goo.gl/DQaHT) and the [FragmentLayout.java](http://goo.gl/rzbV8) example from the ApiDemos SDK sample project.

I ran the tests on an actual Revue with the beta version of Google TV 2.0.  In the first case I only defined two fragments just like the example layout and the global fragment contained my app icon automatically (and nothing else).